# Export GridView to comma delimited .txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm exporting some data from a GridView to a .txt file.
This is the code:

```
private void ExportGridToExcel()
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    string FileName = "Export" + DateTime.Now + ".txt";
    StringBuilder strbldr = new StringBuilder();
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        //separting header columns text with comma operator
        strbldr.Append(GridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    //appending new line for gridview header row
    strbldr.Append("\n");
    for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < GridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            //separating gridview columns with comma
            strbldr.Append(GridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Text + ',');
            strbldr.Replace("&lt;", "<");
            strbldr.Replace("&gt;", ">");
        }
        //appending new line for gridview rows
        strbldr.Append("\n");
    }
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    Response.Output.Write(strbldr.ToString());
    Response.End();
}


protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ExportGridToExcel();

}
```

This works, however I need to remove all html tags in the export as the above code seems to add `<p>` tags to the different columns? Anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: Could you not use the Replace function and replace the HTML with a blank? strbldr.Replace("HTML", "");

Answer (score 0):

You could use utility function based on regex to remove html tags:

```
public string RemoveHtmlTags(string source)
{
    return Regex.Replace(source, "<.*?>", "");
}
```

This will replace all tags like "<b>" or "<span/>" with empty string.